# Why can't I edit an appended textarea?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I'm trying to append a textarea to a `div`.  Once the textarea is appended I can't select it to start typing until I resize the browser window.  How can I make it selectable on the first time?

```
<script>
$("#distraction-mode").click(function(e){ // Entering the distraction mode
        e.preventDefault();
    $("#wysiwyg").appendTo("#wysiwyg-fullscreen");
});
</script>

<div id="wysiwyg-fullscreen-container">
    <div id="wysiwyg-fullscreen"></div> <!-- div where textarea will be -->
</div>

<div id="wysiwyg">
    <textarea id="editor" name="editor" rows="" cols=""></textarea>
    <a href="#" id="distraction-mode">Distraction Mode</a>
</div>
```

Comment: Could you please post you code here?

Comment: [Your example](http://jsfiddle.net/DB2Ev/) works for me.

Comment: well I'm using CLEditor text editor. I don't know if that have something to do or not.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A guess but you could call `.refresh()` on your textarea, and then `.focus()`.

This is based on the documentation [here](http://premiumsoftware.net/cleditor/docs/GettingStarted.html)

**EDIT**
You will need to have the editor set to a variable so that you have access to it and to be able to call functions on it specifically. Using `refresh()` and `focus()` after you append it to another element will hopefully allow it to resize and reset itself.

It might look something like this:

```
<script>
var editor = $("#editor").cleditor()[0];

$("#distraction-mode").click(function(e){
  // Entering the distraction mode
  e.preventDefault();
  $("#wysiwyg").appendTo("#wysiwyg-fullscreen");
  editor.refresh();
  editor.focus();
});
</script>
```

Comment: and where I put that .refresh() and then .focus() al3xnull? Sorry to ask this, but I'm just starting to know about Javascript and jQuery.

Comment: ahah found it. Thanks anyway for the big help